# In 12.04 LTS, I get "No DBus" errors when running things as root

Tags: 12.04, root, dbus

While attempting to run gEdit as root from a terminal window (was trying to do some tweaking on my HOSTS and FSTAB files), I get a message saying "No DBus connection available" and get booted back to the prompt.

However, I can run Nautilus from the prompt like that (still get the error, but it runs all the same), and use WINE and NOTEPAD, and was able to make my changes.

I thought maybe DBUS was missing, but APT says it's installed and gEdit runs fine when not elevated. Granted, I don't have to elevate often, but on the off-chance I do, (like adding or changing SMB/CIFS mountpoints in FSTAB), I would like to use gEdit, not NOTEPAD from WINE, and not in a terminal window with VI (well VIM).

Ideas? Solutions?

Comment: How are you launching gedit?

Comment: Isn't it not advisable to run apps like that with `sudo` instead of `gksu`. I forgot the reason why it's not advised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since upgrading to 12.10, I don't have this issue any more, so I'm closing this question.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem on Fedora 17 and the solution was just to use `su -` instead of `su`.

But maybe your problem is something different, don't know.

[Source](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=260040)

Answer (score 1):

As the first entry above stated, while using Linux Mint 14 I also received this error when opening Gedit to edit my `fstab` file by using `su` <kbd>Enter</kbd> enter password then gedit. I did it again using `su` - and the problem did not occur.